# error: ‘blockIdx’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: cuda, gpu

I try to write a GPU program using CUDA. Below is my function:

```
__global__ static void
histogram_gpu(int * hist_out, unsigned char * img_in, int img_size, int nbr_bin){
    int i;
    const int bid = blockIdx.x;
    const int tid = threadIdx.x;
    // for ( i = 0; i < img_size; i ++){
    //     hist_out[img_in[i]] ++;
    // }
    for (i = bid*THREAD_NUM + tid; i < img_size; i += BLOCK_NUM*THREAD_NUM) {
        hist_out[img_in[i]]++;
    }
}
```

When I call this function in the main function, there's an error occurs:

```
error: ‘blockIdx’ was not declared in this scope
```

I use the CUDA 5.0 on my MAC machine, and below is the Makefile:

```
OSUPPER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
OSLOWER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])

# Flags to detect 32-bit or 64-bit OS platform
OS_SIZE = $(shell uname -m | sed -e "s/i.86/32/" -e "s/x86_64/64/")
OS_ARCH = $(shell uname -m | sed -e "s/i386/i686/")

# These flags will override any settings
ifeq ($(i386),1)
    OS_SIZE = 32
    OS_ARCH = i686
endif

ifeq ($(x86_64),1)
    OS_SIZE = 64
    OS_ARCH = x86_64
endif

# Flags to detect either a Linux system (linux) or Mac OSX (darwin)
DARWIN = $(strip $(findstring DARWIN, $(OSUPPER)))

# Location of the CUDA Toolkit binaries and libraries
CUDA_PATH       ?= /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0
CUDA_INC_PATH   ?= $(CUDA_PATH)/include
CUDA_BIN_PATH   ?= $(CUDA_PATH)/bin

ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
  CUDA_LIB_PATH  ?= $(CUDA_PATH)/lib
else
  ifeq ($(OS_SIZE),32)
    CUDA_LIB_PATH  ?= $(CUDA_PATH)/lib
  else
    CUDA_LIB_PATH  ?= $(CUDA_PATH)/lib64
  endif
endif

# Common binaries
NVCC            ?= $(CUDA_BIN_PATH)/nvcc
GCC             ?= g++

# Extra user flags
EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS ?=
EXTRA_LDFLAGS   ?=

# CUDA code generation flags
GENCODE_SM10    := -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10
GENCODE_SM20    := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20
GENCODE_SM30    := -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
GENCODE_FLAGS   := $(GENCODE_SM10) $(GENCODE_SM20) $(GENCODE_SM30)

GENCODE_FLAGS   := $(GENCODE_SM10) $(GENCODE_SM20) $(GENCODE_SM30)

# OS-specific build flags
# ifneq ($(DARWIN),) 
#       LDFLAGS   := -Xlinker -rpath $(CUDA_LIB_PATH) -L$(CUDA_LIB_PATH) -lcudart -lcublas -lcuda -lcufft -ltlshook 
#       CCFLAGS   := -arch $(OS_ARCH) 
# else
#   ifeq ($(OS_SIZE),32)
#       LDFLAGS   := -L$(CUDA_LIB_PATH) -lcudart
#       CCFLAGS   := -m32
#   else
      LDFLAGS   := -L$(CUDA_LIB_PATH)  -lcudart -lcublas -lcuda -lcufft -ltlshook
      CCFLAGS   := -m64
#   endif
# endif

# OS-architecture specific flags
ifeq ($(OS_SIZE),32)
      NVCCFLAGS := -m32
else
      NVCCFLAGS := -m64
endif

# Debug build flags
ifeq ($(dbg),1)
      CCFLAGS   += -g
      NVCCFLAGS += -g -G
      TARGET := debug
else
      TARGET := release
endif


# Common includes and paths for CUDA
INCLUDES      := -I$(CUDA_INC_PATH) -I. -I.. -I../../common/inc


# Add source files here
EXECUTABLE  := 5kk70-assignment-gpu
# Cuda source files (compiled with cudacc)
CUFILES     := 
# C/C++ source files (compiled with gcc / c++)
CCFILES     := main.cpp histogram-equalization.cu contrast-enhancement.cu

################################################################################
# Rules and targets
# All Phony Targets
.PHONY : everything clean

# Default starting position
everything : $(EXECUTABLE)

# Common includes and paths for CUDA
# INCLUDES      := -I$(CUDA_INC_PATH) -I. -I.. -I$(CUDA_INC_PATH)/samples/common/inc/

# Clean OBJECTS
clean :
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJ)

$(EXECUTABLE) : $(CCFILES)
    $(NVCC) -o $@ $^ $(INCLUDES) $(LDFLAGS) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS)
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Have you included `cuda_runtime.h` in your code?

Comment: How does your `main()` function look like?

Comment: sgar91: including `cuda_runtime.h` shouldn't be necessary as main.cpp gets compiled by nvcc here.

Comment: Is the kernel definition inside main.cpp?

Answer (score 25):

This problem will occur when you are writing cuda code that is inside a file named .cpp, and you go to compile it.  Rename the file to .cu, and the compiler will not complain at you.

Comment: Facing a similar issue using qt, my mistake was to not use `.h` file and trying instead to directly import the `.cu` file.

Comment: can you explain more? i didn't get the point @Delgan

Comment: @morteza 4 years later, I don't remember the details... :') What I know is that you (probably) need both `.cu` (definition) and `.h` (declaration) files for your CUDA functions, and you must `#include` the `.h` when you intend to call these functions from C++ (which seems logical).

Comment: i think this is not enough. i am still getting the same error. thanks. @Delgan

Comment: I can't use cuda API in *.h and *.cuh file either. So if I want to use cuda API,  do I have to  name the file as *.cu? But if i do this, i will have to write `#include *.cu` instead of `#include *.h`

Answer (score 1):

In a bazel build rule, try putting the .cu.cc file in the hdrs rather than srcs.